# Ubuntu 16.04, Dual Monitors: Nvidia GTX GeForce 970, Intel i7-4790K iGPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I have a HDMI out from both my Nvidia GTX GeForce 970 GPU, and my Intel i7-4790K iGPU, going to two separate screens.

I'm trying to make a regular dual monitor set-up, like I have managed easily with Windows.

I have tried every possible driver and X11 config I can find on the internet, but to no avail. The closest I have managed to achieve is a login-loop with both screens operational glitch-ily operational.

Has anyone ever set this configuration up before and has a instructions or guidance?

Many thanks.

Comment: it shouldnt be that hard. i just open nvidia xserver settings and configure the monitors there.  I use the proprietary tested drivers in software&updates>additional drivers.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaMultiMonitors

Answer (score 1):

For one, you'll want the proprietary Nvidia drivers like Frank mentioned.

Another thing which should help: from what you said it sounds like you have one monitor running off of your CPU (through the mother board), and one running off of the GPU. I would recommend running both monitors off of your Nvidia GPU. The 970 can definitely support it, and it's likely to cut down on a lot of the trouble you're having.